# When a key is down who sends to the window a message before the systems sends WM_KEYDOWN?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, spy++

I have a Java chat applet that runs in the jp2launcher.exe and I want to make a simple  tool to simulate keyboard messages and send them to the chat window, but I failed. :(

After observing the messages sent to the chat window using Microsoft spy++ I found that the chat window receives addition messages even before the `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_CHAR` , `WM_KEYUP` messages when I press a key.

This is the sequence of the messages received by a regular window when I pressed the "ENTER" key

[image: normal messages]

And this is the sequence of the messages received by the Java applet window window when I pressed the "ENTER" key

[image: upnormal messages]

As you notices the Java window received another one registered message from "someone" ! right before every system message. Who is sending this message before even the system? and what does it mean?

Additional information: when I use PostMessage api function and send `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages it success only if the window is appear and focused and these extra messages appear in spy++ but when I post them while the chat window is minimized or has no focus only my messages go to the window and not these extra messages and of-curse the key don't effect the window as it suppose to do.

**Who is sending these extra messages right before the system sends it's `WM_KEYDOWN` message?**

Comment: Apparently it is something sent by your Java VM. It is possible to send [custom messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a window. 0xC000 and upwards are "String messages for use by applications."  Possibly it could be a message corresponding to the high level "event" for which you'll be able to implement a handler?

Comment: @Lundin how can the java VM send a message to a window before the system message arrives to the window?

Comment: @user5407848 Create an empty project and try this. Put these empty three lines at top of your file `#define CM_FIRST (WM_APP+0)` `#define CM_SECOND (WM_APP+1)` `#define CM_THIRD (WM_APP+2)`. Then in your `WndProc()` before the switch try this. `if(msg == WM_KEYDOWN) { SendMessage(hwnd, CM_FIRST, 0, 0); SendMessage(hwnd, CM_SECOND, 0, 0); SendMessage(hwnd, CM_THIRD, 0, 0); }`  Look at Spy++ and you'll see something similar. The `if(msg == WM_KEYDOWN)` has to be the very first thing at the top of `WndProc()`, right after the opening { of `WndProc()`

Comment: The Java VM does this by having a custom message loop. Where you would type `TranslateMessage()`, it would do something before that. That's what the dialog manager does (which you can do with `IsDialogMessage()`); that's what accelerators do; that's what MFC `PreTranslateMessage()` handlers do, etc. Not uncommon. You'll need to consult AWT documentation for details on these custom messages if they are even intended to be public.

Comment: @Rm32a but this code means the WM_KEYDOWN has posted to the window before the registered message, is that right?  this is not the case here. . what is confusing me is when I press "enter" key while the window has the focus it receives the registered window "before" the WM_KEYDOWN  !

Comment: [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) can receive a message before a window does.

Comment: They could also "subclass" the window.

Comment: @andlabs thank you please check this new update  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356676/what-is-the-difference-between-the-keyboard-input-messages-posted-by-the-system

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't know much about reverse engineering but I disassembled the java process and I found a call to `CallMsgFilter` after `GetMessage` message loop , so I think they implement some hook as you expected , thank you :) , please check this new update  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356676/what-is-the-difference-between-the-keyboard-input-messages-posted-by-the-system

Comment: @Lundin why subclass the window since it is 100% custom window? they build all it's functionality. what do you mean by "subclass" the window?